# TinyMCE uploadImages() function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am trying to use TinyMCE as a WYSIWYG editor. However, when I try to upload an image to my server, I get an error that states:

> Cannot read property 'uploadImages' of undefined

I am reading the exact documentation, but for some reason it's not recognizing the function. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="resources/css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <form>
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title">

            <label>Description</label>
            <input type="text" name="desct">

            <textarea id="editor"></textarea>

            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#editor',
        theme: 'modern',
        browser_spellcheck: true,
        height: 480,
        images_upload_url: 'resources/scripts/postAcceptor.php',
        images_upload_base_path: '/tutorials/resources/images/',
        images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
            this.activeEditor.uploadImages(function(success) {
              $.post('resources/scripts/postAcceptor.php', this.activeEditor.getContent()).done(function() {
                console.log("Uploaded images and posted content as an ajax request.");
              });
            });
        },
        plugins: [
            'advlist autolink link code image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker',
            'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking',
            'save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor'
        ],

        toolbar: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image | print preview media fullpage | forecolor backcolor emoticons | fontselect'
    });

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

the error is that inside the function that it is in `images_upload_handler` key, the code tries to get `this.activeEditor`, but this variable is returning `undefined`

```
images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
    this.activeEditor.uploadImages(function(success) {
       $.post('resources/scripts/postAcceptor.php', this.activeEditor.getContent()).done(function() {
          console.log("Uploaded images and posted content as an ajax request.");
       });
   });
},
```

Based on this documentation https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/ looks like it should be `tinymce.activeEditor`.

PS: Im not quiet sure what are you trying to do. If I understand correctly, you shouldnt execute the post method, it should do it by itself, you should only send a function that will be executed after the post is completed successfully or failed. If you put that post method inside that handler, maybe it will be uploaded twice. Take a look to the full featured demo: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/full-featured/

Comment: I'm trying to do this: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/upload-images/ the uploadImages() function isn't working at all. I'm just trying to send images the user uploads to the server.

Comment: @user2896120 oh I see, but in the example it doesnt make it through the JSON config, it looks like it is outside of everything. He sends the function  to the `tinymce.activeEditor.uploadImages` method